# How does CMake handle shared-library upgrades?

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries

I have a project where I link to boost; the `CMakeLists.txt` looks like this:

```
project(test VERSION 1.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/g++)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g3 -Wall -Wextra -Wfloat-equal -Wundef -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -Wlogical-op -Wredundant-decls -Wshadow -Woverloaded-virtual")

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS filesystem program_options log log_setup REQUIRED)

include_directories(
  ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(test src/test.cpp)

target_link_libraries(test 
  LINK_PUBLIC 
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
    config++
)

install(TARGETS test DESTINATION /usr/bin)
```

Now I am stumped how the linking in CMake works under the hood. It compiles fine but after I upgraded Boost, I am getting the error

```
test: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_program_options.so.1.75.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

and I'd like to avoid having to recompile every time a library gets an update.
The CMake doc says that

> The LINK_PUBLIC and LINK_PRIVATE modes can be used to specify both the link dependencies and the link interface in one command.

But I don't quite understand how or why CMake links to the specific version of Boost and not simply to `/usr/lib/libboost_program_options.so` which is just a symlink to the currently installed version.

Comment: I guess this is because of the ABI: you cannot upgrade the library without recompiling your app (because e.g. new member may be added to the class changing its binary layout and size). It links to specific version to avoid random crashes that may happen if not recompiled.

Comment: I see, I always thought that was one of the advantages of shared libraries, that you do not have to recompile after a library upgrade. But I am disinclined to including it statically. Is there really no other way to handle this?

Comment: On a library's upgrade, old so-version files are usually **not deleted**. So previously installed/compiled software continues to work. Upgrade just adds new so-version library file, and replaces pure `.so` file to point(link) to the so-version one.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I would argue that you cannot make such a universal statement for all linux distributions. E.g. on Arch old versions are removed. I heard the old version could be recovered from `/var/cache/pacman/pkg` , but they are definitely deleted from the usual location.